# plantuml activity diagram with parallel split execution joining in reverse order

Tags: uml, plantuml, activity-diagram

I have this plant UML diagram with split lines. Now I want to change the notation so that I get the modifications drawn in red.

```
@startuml
start
split
   :A;
split again
   :B;
split
:C;
split again
:D;
end split
end split
:E;
end
@enduml
```

[image]

In words:
A is split off early,
later D is split off,
then A joins,
then D shall join later after E.

Thank you

I have a problem to formulate this with embracing split ... end split tags.

Comment: It's clear to me from your diagram what you want to do. However, I believe the semantics of Activity Diagrams (at least the way they're done in PlantUML) won't allow it. A split implies a new activity at the same level. The end split implies that all activities at that level have finished.

Comment: I know of goto, but it is rendered in ugly red lines. Is any other workaround possible?